# remote database host not reacheable from cpanel in codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3, remote-mysql

I have a codeigniter 3 application hosted on cpanel. The database is hosted remotely and I can access it via public ip on localhost without any issue. I have added the app on cpanel and added the remote mysql host ip but i get the error below:

```
    A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 201

Backtrace:

File: /home/*dir*/lms.xxx.com/application/core/MY_Controller.php
Line: 9
Function: __construct

File: /home/*dir*/lms.xxx.com/application/controllers/Login.php
Line: 6
Function: __construct

File: /home/*dir*/lms.xxx.com/index.php
Line: 317
Function: require_once
```

the database.php file looks like this

```
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '41.xx.xxx.xxx',
    'username' => 'root username',
    'password' => 'root pass',
    'database' => 'db name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'port' =>3308,
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'development'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
    
);

remote access host ip is configured as shared below:
[![access_host_ip][1]][1]
 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq5xo.png

Also, on pinging the ip from the cpanel terminal, no response is received. what is the solution to this?
```